# Unique naming in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I easily rename all variable names that are repeated in different scopes to a different one?

e.g. from

```
var a=1;
for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
    var a=2;
    console.log(a+i);

}
```

to

```
var a=1;
for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
    var a1=2;
    console.log(a1+i);

}
```

Comment: Do you really mean scopes, or do you mean blocks? There's only one scope in your example when using `var`.

Comment: Stop declaring variables inside a `for` loop with `var` and you will not cause this problem for yourself.  Declaring all variables at the start of your scope will prevent this type of mistake (by making it more obvious you have a naming conflict).  In newer versions of Javascript you can use `let` instead of `var` to actually have block-scoped variables.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just start using ES2015 and `let`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek for easier program analysis

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `let`

Use `let`:

```
var a=1;
for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
    let a=2;
    ^^^
    console.log(a+i);
}
```

Now, the `a` inside the loop is "scoped" to the loop, and is different from the outside `a`.

From MDN:

> `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the `var` keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.

Since this is ES6, as of the time of this writing, unless you're using Chrome, IE>=11, or node, you will need to use a transpiler such as babel.

#### Using refactoring tools

You could also consider using a tool like grasp: http://www.graspjs.com/blog/2014/01/07/refactoring-javascript-with-grasp/. With grasp you can easily narrow down the scope of the changes, so in this case you could use

```
grasp 'for #a' -R a1 ~/tmp/grasp.js
```

This limits to the changes to the variable `a` to within the `for` loop.

Also, some editors/IDEs have a "refactor" command, which might help if you want to rename the variable instead. Check your IDE's documentation.

#### Roll your own

If you are truly interested in renaming *all* variables which are redeclared in various block scopes to be unique, you would need to end up writing a little program using a parser like esprima to parse the code and modify it yourself; there are also tools written on top of esprima to make doing this kind of thing easier, which you can Google. It sounds harder than it actually is.

Comment: Wouldn't grasp.js change all variables?  That would leave someone in the same position as before, with misunderstanding of block-scoping issues.  `let` is more likely what he would need, but you should encourage the use of babel.js for older versions of ECMAScript

Comment: @vol7ron Thanks. I have added a bit to my answer about how to use grasp to narrow the scope of the changes. Also added information about babel.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any packages (perhaps npm) that can help rename all variable names that are repeated in different scopes to a different one?

No, there are not.

---

Something you might want to do is create your own counter and then review the scoping of the variables individually, but there could potentially be a lot of issues with your parser, since there are many ways to declare/define/initialize a variable:

```
window.global = true;
for(;;){ gobal_reuse = false; }
var simple;
var simple_assignment = true;
var simple, list_variable;
var simple, list_variable, list_assignment = true, list_variable;
for (gobal=true;;) { ... }
while(true){ simple = true; }
for(;;)
  var block_without_brace = true;

// and the list goes on
```